# How should I change header from introduction to outline in beamer?

Tags: beamer, presentations

MWE:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf,tabu}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\useinnertheme{circles}

\newtheorem*{bem}{Bemerkung}
%\def\bibfont{\tiny}
\usepackage{tikz}
\renewcommand{\raggedright}{\leftskip=2pt \rightskip=2pt plus 2cm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
    language=Java,
    aboveskip=2mm,
    belowskip=2mm,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
    numbers=none,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    tabsize=2
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title[Summary thesis]{A short presentation}
\author[PhD]{Rudresh Dwivedi}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
      \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    \section[Introduction]{\tiny{Introduction}}
    \frame[handout:0]{\frametitle{Outline}\tableofcontents[]}
    \normalsize
    \begin{frame}{Introduction}
        Two forms of user authentication:
        \begin{enumerate} 
            \item Knowledge base
            \item Tokens
        \end{enumerate} 
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should insert all the required packages, as well as `\documentclass` so the code is self contained and actually runs :)

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Edited

Answer (score 2):

The header shows the name of the current section. If you want "Outline" to be written there, make a section of this name.

Additional comments:

- many of your packages are unnecessary, for example `color`, `xcolor`, `graphicx` etc.
- don't load the same package multiple times, especially not with different options
- `\tiny` is a switch and does not take an argument, but anyway it is not good to mess with formatting instructions in the argument of sectioning command, better set the appropriate beamer template `\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{size=\tiny}`

---

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf,tabu}
\usepackage{array,longtable}
%\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
%\usepackage{pgf}
%\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetheme{Antibes}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\useoutertheme{infolines}
\useinnertheme{circles}

\newtheorem*{bem}{Bemerkung}
%\def\bibfont{\tiny}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\renewcommand{\raggedright}{\leftskip=2pt \rightskip=2pt plus 2cm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
    language=Java,
    aboveskip=2mm,
    belowskip=2mm,
    showstringspaces=false,
    columns=flexible,
    basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
    numbers=none,
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
    stringstyle=\color{mauve},
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    tabsize=2
}

\setbeamerfont{section in toc}{size=\tiny}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title[Summary thesis]{A short presentation}
\author[PhD]{Rudresh Dwivedi}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
      \titlepage
    \end{frame}
        \section{Outline}
    \frame[handout:0]{\frametitle{Outline}\tableofcontents[]}
        \section[Introduction]{Introduction}
%    \normalsize
    \begin{frame}{Introduction}
        Two forms of user authentication:
        \begin{enumerate} 
            \item Knowledge base
            \item Tokens
        \end{enumerate} 
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way without making outline a section...i.e.  \section{Outline}. I dont want Outline listed as a section in outline not me not anyone else

Comment: @rudreshdwivedi         `\section*{Outline}`